# swift tag needs disambiguation

Tags: support, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

I just noticed that [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) seems to be associated questions relating to two wildly different topics:

1. [SWIFT](http://www.swift.com/) - the interbank messaging system
2. [Swift](http://swift.openstack.org/) - the distributed object/blob store for OpenStack

The tag itself does not have a wiki entry.

Is there an approved way of clearing up this kind of thing?

Comment: No holds barred cage match between the two tags.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an approved way of clearing up this kind of thing?

Once there is an agreement about which tag to use, the 24 questions can be retagged to use the correct tag. The task can be done in one day, possibly in the days like Saturday, and Sunday, to avoid cluttering the front page with old questions.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to keep [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) for the OpenStack related questions, since this is the majority of them, and retag the others with [swift-messaging](/questions/tagged/swift-messaging) or something similar.